# Delete Row in a Table View

Tags: swift, tableview, tablecell

I recently fixed a few errors I had in this code, but a new one showed up and me and my teacher haven't been able to fix it. It says "expected declaration"
How do I fix this?

```
import UIKit

    class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

        var StoredValues = Values()
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
        }
        override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
            super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }

        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return 4
        }
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "meunSegue", sender: self)

            func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
                _ = segue.destination as! SecondViewController
            }
            class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

                var recievedData = ""
                override func viewDidLoad() {
                    super.viewDidLoad()
                    print(recievedData)
                }
            }
        }
        - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView committEditStyle: (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [maTheData removeObjectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];


        }
    }
```

Comment: Look for another teacher who has at least basic knowledge. You are nesting delegate methods and even class declarations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to mix Object-C and Swift in the same file.  Below would be the Swift 3 version of your code.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        maTheData.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
    }
}
```

Comment: @vadian It will compile if you add `var maTheData: [NSManagedObject] = []`  This was just to show them the Swift version of the code that they had as Objective-C in the Swift file.

Comment: @vadian It will compile for me what way it just will not show the delete function, but you are correct it should be commit.